# Config parameter not reading from other locations

Tags: python, flask

The parameter is not read from files other than the run.py . run.py is the Flask startup script

from run.py :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
print(app.config["PARAMETER"])
```

From any other python file in project following error is returned :

```
KeyError: 'PARAMETER'
```

How to read configuration file from other locations within project other than startup script file ?

Update :

Reading config file :

```
app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(".", "myconfig.conf"))
```

Contents of myconfig.conf :

```
PARAMETER = "test"
```

Comment: I cannot see any code loads config.

Comment: @Sraw thanks, please see update.

Comment: @blue-sky - please pick some answer at your liking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just simply missed loading parameters.

If you do inline loadign of parameters, you would specifiy it as:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['PARAMETER_1'] = 'test'
assert app.config["PARAMETER_1"] == 'test'
```

The code above works, now how can one load similar data from file?

```
# prepare file 
from pathlib import Path
Path("myconfig.conf").write_text("PARAMETER_2 = 'test2'\n")

# load it    
app.config.from_pyfile("myconfig.conf")
# test it
assert app.config["PARAMETER_2"] == 'test2'
```

Comment: It's considered a bad practice to set the parameters manually and even more if those parameters are the `SECRET_KEY` or some API key.

Comment: @Evgeny Pogrebnyak I'm attempting to read a configuration file property from any location in python project, but it appears can just read from the startup script. Can configuration be read from any python file in project ?

Comment: @blue-sky: do you mean load the parameters or access them after they are loaded? wherever you have the flask instance available you can do both, but that does not seem very useful outside the 'startup script': you define your flask instance there, the rest of the files are usually different abstractions, eg views, models, helpers.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak yes I mean access them after they are loaded - access a custom configuration in a file other than the startup script.

Comment: @blue-sky: I think we differ on terminology - action 1 is loading parameters from file to flask instance, action 2 is accessing the flask instance parameters. I'm confused which one causes trouble, but perhaps a separate example with two files is needed, eg app.py and modifier.py. This is related, but a separate question - consider a new question with a bit of detail on intended behaviour and motivation, why you do this. Maybe you dont need that functionality for the task you solving.

Comment: Noted, will consider posting a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the `PARAMETER` key after the creation of the `app` because there is no any key into its configuration object which its name is `PARAMETER`. In order to do it, first create the app, import a simple object which holds the configuration and then use `app.config.from_object(Config)`

```
#config.py
class Config(object):
    PARAMETER = 'my-parameter-value'
    #you can add another keys
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'


#__init__.py
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__);
app.config.from_object(Config)
```

Comment: your example does proper init of parameters, but I think OP is asking about init from file, not from object